# Why sys:hostName property in log4j2-spring.xml returns just hostname and not host and domain both in JDK 17?

Tags: migration, hostname

I am migrating a spring boot application from spring boot 2 to spring boot 3 which requires to upgrade Java too.

Why in JDK 1.8 log4j2-spring.xml ${sys:hostName:-NA} returns host & domain name ie. uk202301.cloud.mycompany where as in JDK 17 it returns
just hostName ie. uk202301 ?
See file name in JDK 1.8 highlighted below

- Java Version: **JDK1.8.0**_121-X64
- Spring Boot Version 2.7.14
- Log4j: 2.17.1
- OS: RedHat

Returns file name as

- fileName:
  **uk202301.cloud.mycompany_myappuser_myproject-discovery-service_file.log**

Where as file name in JDK 17 highlighted below

- Java Version: **jdk-17.0**.0-X64
- Spring Boot Version: 3.1.3
- Log4j: 2.20.0
- OS: RedHat
  Returns file name as
- fileName: **uk202301_myappuser_myproject-discovery-service_file.log**

```
 <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="rollingFile"
         **fileName**="${sys:LOG_DIR:-/tmp}/${sys:hostName:-NA}_${env:USER:-NA}_${sys:LOG_FILE_STEM:-app}_file.log"
         filePattern="${sys:LOG_DIR:-/tmp}/../archive/${sys:hostName:-NA}_${env:USER:-NA}_${sys:LOG_FILE_STEM:-app}_file.log.%i.gz"
         immediateFlush="false">
        ..
    </Appenders>
```

Where
`-DLOG_DIR= /myproject/log/myappuser/myproject-discovery-service -DLOG_FILE_STEM=myproject-discovery-service -DLOG_FILE_STEM=myproject-discovery-service`

Found some reference but not much clear to me.
[Why java getHostName gives the FQDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207901/why-java-gethostname-gives-the-fqdn/59217450#59217450)